# How calculate the Datatable final total amount

Tags: php, jquery

i am writing report for my daliy sales.when i tried to calculate  the final total amount output display as undefined
i checked the total using  alert message output display as undefined
i don't what was the error is . what i tried so far i attached below

```
var total = 0;
function get_all() {
    var from_date = $('#from_date').val();
    var to_date   = $('#to_date').val();

    $('#tbl-projects').dataTable().fnDestroy();

    $.ajax({
        url      : "../php/report/all_sales.php",
        type     : "POST",
        dataType : 'JSON',
        data     : { from_date : from_date, to_date : to_date },
        async    : false,
        success  : function (data) {         
            $('#tbl-projects').dataTable({
                dom         : 'Bfrtip',
                buttons     : [
                    'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
                ],
                "aaData"    : data,
                "scrollX"   : true,
                "aoColumns" : [
                    {"sTitle": "Invoice No", "mData": "id"},
                    {"sTitle": "Date",       "mData": "date"},
                    {"sTitle": "Total",      "mData": "total"},
                    {"sTitle": "Pay",        "mData": "pay"},
                    {"sTitle": "Due",        "mData": "due"},
                ]
            });

            total += Number(total);
            alert(total);
        },
        error    : function (xhr) {
            console.log('Request Status: ' + xhr.status  );
            console.log('Status Text: ' + xhr.statusText );
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
            var text = $($.parseHTML(xhr.responseText)).filter('.trace-message').text();
            console.log(text)
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: where does total variable come from at first? just to let you get_all() can not reach var total = 0, also total += Number(total); what do u mean about this

Comment: all_sales.php page i am retrieving the data all data comes successfully . total also but couldn't calculating the final total

Comment: write total = 0 as first line of your function get_all()  or make total as global variable without var keyword + how do you extract the total from ajx data response, i think it should be something like data.total or something else

Comment: i just create variable as  var total = 0 ; and get the out put json than calculating values

Comment: yes sir.   data.total  but i can't calculating the value can you write the one for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Total` variable is defined outside of the function, rather you define total inside the function or just make it global var.

The summation line `total += Number(total);`  needs to take the `total` from `data ajax response` inside a loop.

So your function can be like the following:

```
       function get_all() {
            var total=0;//local varialble
            var from_date = $('#from_date').val();
            var to_date = $('#to_date').val();
            $('#tbl-projects').dataTable().fnDestroy();

            $.ajax({
                url:"../php/report/all_sales.php",

                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'JSON',
                data:{from_date:from_date, to_date:to_date},
                async:false,
                success: function (data) {

                    $('#tbl-projects').dataTable({
                        dom: 'Bfrtip',
                        buttons: [
                            , 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
                        ],

                        "aaData": data
                        ,
                        "scrollX": true,
                        "aoColumns": [
                            {"sTitle": "Invoice No", "mData": "id"},
                            {"sTitle": "Date", "mData": "date"},
                            {"sTitle": "Total", "mData": "total"},
                            {"sTitle": "Pay", "mData": "pay"},
                            {"sTitle": "Due", "mData": "due"},

                        ]


                    });

                   data.forEach(function(recordInLoop) {
                        total += Number(recordInLoop.total);
                   });

                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    console.log('Request Status: ' + xhr.status  );
                    console.log('Status Text: ' + xhr.statusText );
                    console.log(xhr.responseText);
                    var text = $($.parseHTML(xhr.responseText)).filter('.trace-message').text();
                    console.log(text)
                }
            });


        }
```

Comment: output display NAN

Comment: alert message NAN

Comment: can you alert data.total or all data

Comment: all data displayed successfully sir. if i use data.total through alert message also this was a output NAN

Comment: can you please share what did you get when alert data ?

Comment: this is the output i got the alert data     NAN i got

Comment: right now i am so much confused, I need to see how you return data to ajax from php file

Comment: i am retrieving the data from all_sales.php page. all data coming successfully sir. i edited the all_sales.php above. i check through console.log here out put 0: {id: 39, date: "2018-12-07", total: 11880, pay: 0, due: 11880}
1: {id: 40, date: "2018-12-07", total: 1080, pay: 1080, due: 0}
2: {id: 41, date: "2018-12-07", total: 2160, pay: 2160, due: 0}
3: {id: 42, date: "2018-12-07", total: 3240, pay: 0, due: 3240}
4: {id: 43, date: "2018-12-07", total: 2160, pay: 0, due: 2160}

Comment: but why couldn't calucating value sir

Comment: so the data is an array of many records, thats way, you need a loop, i just updated the answer to add foreach loop

Comment: total += Number(totalInLoop);
                        console.log(total);   i checked sir same output displayed NAN

Comment: total += Number(totalInLoop.total);

Comment: 11880
 12960 15120
 18360 20520 22680 values are displayed not calculated the final output

Comment: your final total should be printed outside of the loop, come on man, `data.forEach(function(recordInLoop) {
                        total += Number(recordInLoop.total);
                   }); alert(total);`

Comment: sir how to print the total amout below the table plesae help me

Comment: actually I am not sure, you need to search about 'dataTable' how to add sum in footer

Comment: i seached that one sir but couln't do it if you help i never forget you alot